# Can I use MailSender in Spring without using Javabeans?

Tags: spring, maven

If so how should I initialize MailSender?

```
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;

public class EmailErrorReporting {
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public void sendEmail(String email, String text)    {
        SimpleMailMessage simpleMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        simpleMessage.setFrom("alee@email.com");
        simpleMessage.setTo(email);
        simpleMessage.setText(text);
        MailSender sender = null;
        sender.send(simpleMessage);
    }
}
```

The email I'm trying to send is just simple text.

Comment: Is this working for you? If not what does it do?

Comment: @jakub.petr, it wouldn't as he is setting `MailSender` variable to null and is looking for help on how to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant "without spring beans" when you said "without using javabeans", then you have to create your own instance of an implementation of JavaMailSender, like [JavaMailSenderImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring/2.0.5/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl.java), a public class, set all the required properties like host, port, protocol and then call `send()` method with your message.

You could probably take a look at [this page](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/27/send-email-with-spring-javamailsenderimpl-example/) and instantiate your `JavaMailSenderImpl` object based on the attributes defined in the bean definition.